# Error when converting timestamp to string in liquid (json)

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I'm using Logic Apps to transform my data before storing. For this I'm using json to json built in converter which use liquid. 
Here's my raw input ,

```
{  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "metadata":{  
      "generated":1539147197000,
      "url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2018-10-09T04:53:16.6743076Z",
      "title":"USGS Earthquakes",
      "status":200,
      "api":"1.5.8",
      "count":245
   },
   "features":[  
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "mag":1.9,
            "place":"118km NNW of Arctic Village, Alaska",
            "time":1539146474786,
            "updated":1539146692433,
            "tz":-540,
            "url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak20275217",
            "detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=ak20275217&format=geojson",
            "felt":null,
            "cdi":null,
            "mmi":null,
            "alert":null,
            "status":"automatic",
            "tsunami":0,
            "sig":56,
            "net":"ak",
            "code":"20275217",
            "ids":",ak20275217,",
            "sources":",ak,",
            "types":",geoserve,origin,",
            "nst":null,
            "dmin":null,
            "rms":1.17,
            "gap":null,
            "magType":"ml",
            "type":"earthquake",
            "title":"M 1.9 - 118km NNW of Arctic Village, Alaska"
         },
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               -146.6925,
               69.1011,
               0
            ]
         },
         "id":"ak20275217"
      },
...(list continues)
```

This is the liquid file I have as mapped in the logic app,

```
{
    "Data": [
        {% for f in content.features %}
        {
            "type": "{{f.properties.type}}",
            "mag": {{f.properties.mag}},
            "place": "{{f.properties.place}}",
            "time": "{{f.properties.time}}",
            "tsunami": {{f.properties.tsunami}},
            "code": "{{f.properties.code}}",
            "ids": "{{f.properties.ids}}",
            "magType": "{{f.properties.magType}}",
            "source": "{{f.properties.sources}}",
            "longitude": {{f.geometry.coordinates[0]}},
            "latitude": {{f.geometry.coordinates[1]}}
        },
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

It actually gives the required output but for the time field it just gives an error as given below,

> "time": "Liquid error: Value was either too large or too small for an
>   Int32.",

I tried to convert this field into a string using [this guide](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-can-i-convert-a-number-to-a-string-185373),

However nothing seems to work and it gives an type conversion error. 
I just want to save the time value as it is (even as a string) in the raw input file which is a Unix Epoch timestamp.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Append: '' | f.time

The key is to coerce it to a string first.

Comment: Try with a space then. ' '